# Is there any way to avoid errors while executing migrations during work with Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Following is the error which I am facing.

[ErrorException]
include(/home/in-techouse/Projects/qidigo/qidigo/vendor/composer/../../database/migrations/2020_12_16_135219_add_last_played_at_to_presentations.php): failed to open stream:

Scnario Explained:

1. I have created a migration with the name of "020_12_16_135219_add_last_played_at_to_presentations.php" and also executed it in my local environment and then switched to another branch.
2. Over here migration file is not available but in the migrations table record of executed migration exists.

Please tell me which Laravel standards overcome this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically, your migrations should run fine if you keep creating new files and make sure they are ran in order of creation. Then if anyone pulls in the repo, the missing migrations should run in the correct order as well and everything should be fine.

But I cant quite tell from your question if files are renamed. If so, then you're out of luck since you cant trust the `migrations` table contents anymore (which Laravel creates for you) since it says a migration with filename `"x"` has been ran, but it has been renamed since. So the next time you `php artisan migrate` that renamed migration will run since it is not in the `migrations` table.

However I encounter these issues mostly in the startup phases of a project. If you have a lot of database refactoring to do I suggest you do it all at once.

You can always locally do `php artisan migrate:refresh` to reset your database to the new structure (all data will be removed though), but this command will probably run into errors too if it is trying to rollback renamed files which it can't find anymore.